# How to catch the stdio from a python subroutine?

Tags: python, io

I have the following codes:

```
def fsub():
  print 'OK'

def fmain():
  a = fsub()

fmain()
```

Apparently `fsub()` won't return 'OK' and assign to `a` in `fmain()`. However, this is what I want. Is there anyway we can make it **without changing** `fsub()`?

Comment: You should go back and accept the most relevant answers to some of our questions.

Comment: @HailiangZhang, usually after asking, you accept the best answer clicking on the check symbol. You haven't done this, not even once, for all your 10 questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `a = fsub()`, you're trying to assing `a` the return of `fsub()`, in this case `None` (because `fsub()` doesn't return anything).

The correct thing to do is to redirect the stdout to a file, then call the `fsub()` function, and the redirect back the stdout to the original stdout:

```
import sys

def fmain():
    sys.stdout = open('output','a')
    fsub()
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    print 'Output of fsub():'
    print open('output').read(),
    # added the coma (,) to avoid a new line
```

Result:

```
>>> fmain()
Output of fsub():
OK
```

Comment: Sorry I need to rephrase my question. Please see the original question again...

Comment: I need to get the printed output from fsub in fmain

Comment: I would suggest using a `StringIO` object rather than a file.